# Flannel network not getting configured correctly, how to fix that?

Tags: kubernetes

I created an nginx deployment and got below error.

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl describe pod nginx
Name:           nginx-6799fc88d8-ltnc5
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           kworker1/10.8.0.70
Start Time:     Wed, 14 Jul 2021 16:26:32 +0000
Labels:         app=nginx
                pod-template-hash=6799fc88d8
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-6799fc88d8
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:       
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-ngqhw (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-ngqhw:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               7m27s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx-6799fc88d8-ltnc5 to kworker1
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  7m27s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "bd465da8133b3b31cea3ccf75b0bbf718336f4a06fea40aeef5ddf9a2ba74b96": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  7m16s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "eb61496041afad0a51a989e1fe1898db37a7356cd1047e0e9bad73d5bfcc9abc": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  7m5s                   kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "a56c7fe7d8b102f38c4a84d514e18f5b995210c8efa3e945f6f12d51fc27b72b": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6m54s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "1ebe31cebdac61145dbacbca661c2595ca267f4112fe77f69e7e1cd1f04b97bf": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6m42s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "3de40514e0b210f27e5fe3e3c70afafef5418a23e1faed886358766d2454d434": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6m29s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "1fba1c9980010c57d1dbb8ed8c6554ca16957f3b1773874fa8d652442212f6ed": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6m17s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "f1296e109c11689f7f01a0c5cb8483b6d47269092dc0851afce21bb17d873dca": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6m6s                   kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "23bfe01e93b6639f4953ee8590576e4c3784a01372afcf609affbd03d5b26398": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  5m51s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "2a589a2995a530c7d9b11abd51e7315852285078d05717aefa6c8f4c0e928866": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  119s (x17 over 5m37s)  kubelet            (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "cd97f555abf734ef27d19ab7a13f1935dbf2e4fd2fca9e9cbb986061f174a46b": open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
```

I applied [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) to create flannel network
Please suggest how to fix this?

lxc containers:

```
dminuser@testing:~/Desktop/kubernetes/lxd-provisioning$ lxc list
+----------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|   NAME   |  STATE  |       IPV4        |                     IPV6                      |   TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+----------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| kmaster  | RUNNING | 10.8.0.129 (eth0) | fd42:666f:471d:3d53:216:3eff:fedb:8af1 (eth0) | CONTAINER | 0         |
+----------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| kworker1 | RUNNING | 10.8.0.229 (eth0) | fd42:666f:471d:3d53:216:3eff:fe93:ca5e (eth0) | CONTAINER | 0         |
+----------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| kworker2 | RUNNING | 10.8.0.152 (eth0) | fd42:666f:471d:3d53:216:3eff:fe23:b3a4 (eth0) | CONTAINER | 0         |
+----------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

some output related to pods:

```
oot@kmaster:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
kmaster    Ready    control-plane,master   3m44s   v1.21.0
kworker1   Ready    <none>                 114s    v1.21.0
kworker2   Ready    <none>                 99s     v1.21.0

oot@kmaster:~# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-558bd4d5db-569mm          0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m1s
coredns-558bd4d5db-pzlfh          0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m1s
etcd-kmaster                      1/1     Running             0          4m4s
kube-apiserver-kmaster            1/1     Running             0          4m4s
kube-controller-manager-kmaster   1/1     Running             0          4m4s
kube-flannel-ds-8mfsv             0/1     Error               2          2m14s
kube-flannel-ds-jv9rg             1/1     Running             4          4m1s
kube-flannel-ds-wms5n             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    2          2m29s
kube-proxy-k8mnl                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    5          4m1s
kube-proxy-mw8ff                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    4          2m14s
kube-proxy-qkpzl                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    4          2m29s
kube-scheduler-kmaster            1/1     Running             0          4m4s
root@kmaster:~# 


oot@kmaster:~# kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-8mfsv 
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kube-flannel-ds-8mfsv" not found
root@kmaster:~# kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-8mfsv -n kube-system
I0715 08:13:32.125253       1 main.go:520] Determining IP address of default interface
I0715 08:13:32.125810       1 main.go:533] Using interface with name eth0 and address 10.8.0.152
I0715 08:13:32.125874       1 main.go:550] Defaulting external address to interface address (10.8.0.152)
W0715 08:13:32.125954       1 client_config.go:608] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
E0715 08:14:02.128488       1 main.go:251] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-8mfsv': Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-8mfsv": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: I can see you've already created a couple of questions about `flannel`. To addition of what suggested, how did you set up your cluster? What pod's CIDR is used? And yes, it looks like flannel pod is crashing. Please check `kubectl get pod -n kube-system' and then `kubectl desribe pod %CRASHING_POD_NAME% -n kube system`. Please update the question with this output

Comment: There is one more problem with lxc containers, after restart of the machine, It is not starting the kubelet process itself on master, so I will create the cluster again and reply with the output in few minutes. ALso, can you please reply to my istio related question also.

Comment: added output for the commands you asked in the master

Comment: Have you fixed your issue with lxc containers? This is the first thing you should start with.